# Easiest/best way to backup/restore RAID 5 array?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, backup, raid

I've tried the built in Windows 10 backup and restore with no success. I've also tried EaseUS Todo Backup and Aomei Backupper with no success.

I'm guessing this is because the backup is written fine, but I cannot restore to a dynamic GPT? Only to a basic? I am confused...

I basically have 3 drives in RAID 5 (1TB each, 2TB usable). I want to basically clone this or make a backup of it and restore it to another brand new 3 drives in RAID 5 (1TB each, 2TB usable).

That's all I want to do. What's the best way of doing this? Would a program like disPaity help? (http://www.vilett.com/disparity/).

I see there are cloning abilities, but I'm confused at the fact that how am I supposed to connect another RAID 5 array of 3 drives to the current system that has the RAID 5 array of 3 drives I want to use as a source? I can see it being easy when it's just 1 drive to 1 drive where you can connect both drives to your computer, but 6 drives (3 from source RAID 5, 3 from destination RAID 5) for cloning?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: "I'm guessing this is because the backup is written fine, but I cannot restore to a dynamic GPT? Only to a basic? I am confused..." - That is a limitation of the software your using.

Comment: @Ramhound, How do I bypass this? So it seems like Windows Backup/Restore and at least 2 third-party software backup/restore programs do this as well. All I'd like to do is just have a backup/restore that can be done on a RAID 5 and/or dynamic GPT setup.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to clone the raid array, what you need to clone is the virtual drives (VD) that you have created.

For example: if you created one big VD, your pc / server and the OS will see one disc drive.

Use any cloning utility that you like and create a backup of the partition or disk as usual to some external source e.g. External hard drive.

If you want to clone this to another pc:

1) re-create the the same raid array on second pc / server.

2) restore the data.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have an off question in regards to the cloning.

So like I said I do have a backup created but I think the reason why I cannot restore it onto the new RAID 5 array is because the old RAID 5 was "basic" while somehow the new RAID 5 array is "dynamic GPT". Would somehow changing my RAID 5 array to be "basic" as well then allow the backup to be restored onto my new array?

Would cloning the VD then restoring it bypass this issue of "basic" vs "dynamic GPT" drives that I think I'm seeing in the sense that, that is why my backups can't be written to my new drives?

Comment: Are you using drives more than 2TB ?

Comment: What cloning software are you using for your  backups ? And what error do you receive ?

Comment: Well I haven't been using cloning yet, only because I don't know how to have my old RAID 5 array (x3 1TB SSDs) on the same computer with my new RAID 5 array (x3 1TB SSDs).

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: 1) Obtain a bootable cd like **Acronis true image**, 2) backup your partition / volumes to external hard drive. 3) disconnect old ssd drive. 4) connect new ssd drives. 5) create the same raid 5 vd. 6) restore the previously created backup.

Comment: If you don't use any cloning / backup software, than how is it that you can't restore ?!

Comment: Disk type is something that you can control basic / gpt, unless you have drive that is larger than 2TB.

Comment: Please explain yourself more accurately if you want to receive help.

Comment: YanivK, I am making backups of my entire drive to my external, then removing my old RAID 5 array, putting in my new RAID 5 array, and trying to restore with no luck. I'm playing with a bit of the settings and such. None of my drives are larger than 1TB. It's stated in my original post. I have 3 SSDs, 1TB each, totaling to a 2TB RAID 5 array of 3 drives.

Comment: Once again, what type of software do you use to create the backup ?

Comment: I seem to have solved the issue on my own. I sued AOMEI Backupper and used "disk backup". The issue I had using that file for restoring my new RAID 5 array was that somehow the new array was set in "dynamic" type instead of "basic". I reformatted the drives to be "basic" then the restoration worked as is. There was an issue with the boot manager, but a quick fix with "bootbcd" did the trick.